# Zurb Foundation + Bundler Setup Dependencies

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler, zurb-foundation

Following [these instructions](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/sass.html#multiple-versions) for running multiple versions of Foundation with Bundler, I was able to create a new project with a dependency of `3.2.5`

Here's my Gemfile:

```
source "https://rubygems.org"
gem "zurb-foundation", "3.2.5"
gem "compass"
```

I then ran `bundle exec compass create . -r zurb-foundation --using foundation` and it created my Gemfile.lock file:

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    chunky_png (1.2.7)
    compass (0.12.2)
      chunky_png (~> 1.2)
      fssm (>= 0.2.7)
      sass (~> 3.1)
    fssm (0.2.9)
    modular-scale (1.0.6)
      compass (>= 0.12.1)
      sass (>= 3.2.0)
      sassy-math (>= 1.5)
    rake (10.0.3)
    sass (3.2.5)
    sassy-math (1.5)
      compass (~> 0.11)
    zurb-foundation (3.2.5)
      compass (>= 0.12.2)
      modular-scale (= 1.0.6)
      rake
      sass (>= 3.2.0)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  compass
  zurb-foundation (= 3.2.5)
```

But - after trying to compile (with Codekit), I'm getting the following:

```
Compass was unable to compile one or more files in the project: 

    error app.scss (Line 1 of _settings.scss: File to import not found or unreadable: foundation/common/ratios.
Load paths:
  /Users/chester/Sites/f3.2.5test/sass
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/compass-0.12.2/frameworks/blueprint/stylesheets
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/compass-0.12.2/frameworks/compass/stylesheets
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/zurb-foundation-4.0.5/scss
  Compass::SpriteImporter)
overwrite app.css 


(This action was triggered by a change to _settings.scss)
```

Which from the looks of it, is still trying to get something from `4.0.5`. Just as a side-note, I recieved this while trying to upgrade Foundation:

```
sudo gem update zurb-foundation
Updating installed gems
Updating zurb-foundation
Fetching: zurb-foundation-4.0.5.gem (100%)
Successfully installed zurb-foundation-4.0.5
Installing RDoc documentation for zurb-foundation-4.0.5
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rdoc/rdoc.rb:280: warning: conflicting chdir during another chdir block
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rdoc/rdoc.rb:287: warning: conflicting chdir during another chdir block
Installing ri documentation for zurb-foundation-4.0.5
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rdoc/rdoc.rb:280: warning: conflicting chdir during another chdir block
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rdoc/rdoc.rb:287: warning: conflicting chdir during another chdir block
Done installing documentation for zurb-foundation after 0 seconds
Gems updated: zurb-foundation
```

But the actual files looked to have installed just fine `gem list`

```
bundler (1.3.2)
chunky_png (1.2.7)
compass (0.12.2)
fssm (0.2.10, 0.2.9)
modular-scale (1.0.6)
rake (10.0.3)
rubygems-update (2.0.2, 1.8.24)
sass (3.2.7, 3.2.5)
sassy-math (1.5)
zurb-foundation (4.0.5, 3.2.5, 3.2.4)
```

I can create/use a F4 project just fine, but for some reason any F3 projects look to be still referencing F4 (and coming up with those unreadable errors). Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

### Update

This appears to be a Codekit issue -- as using the standard `bundle exec compass watch` seems to work just fine. Developer hasn't replied to the issue I made on this -- so anyone else that "has" been able to get this work would make my day to share their insights. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed! Wrote an [article about it](http://zslabs.com/articles/versioned-dependencies-with-compass)